# bt fusion router - wireless and wired not talking

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking

I use a BT Router - the 2wire BT700 HGV.

The wireless devices I have can see each other - eg a desktop connected with wireless can 'see' the iPad which is also connected wirelessly. Machines which are hard wired, however, cannot.

The same applies with, eg, ssh. I can access the command prompt from 1 machine with another using ssh if both machines are hard wired, however not if one is on the wiresll network.

I'm not great with networking - I only know the basics. I've hunted answers for hours multiple times over the past year with little success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the ip address of a wireless device and what is the ip address of a wired device?

Comment: iPad (wireless) is 192.168.178.76
Linux box (wired) is 192.168.1.5

Comment: Generally speaking, you'll want the devices on the same subnet if you want them to talk to each other, which they are not.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Does this refer to the fact that all wired contain a 1 and all wireless a 178? I did notice this, but would not know how to change this. Should this be straight forward? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your particular router, but generally you'll open your browser and go to "http://192.168.1.1" on your wired device to get to the web interface on your router (where you can configure it).

They do have 24 hour support though:  http://www.productsandservices.bt.com/consumerProducts/displayTopic.do?topicId=25824

Comment: Thanks. I can access the control panel, I'm just not really sure I know what I'm trying to achieve. Am I simply trying to set the 'subnet mask' to the same value for both wired and wireless? I did contact BT about this but was told this is outwith the level of support I have!

Answer (score 0):

Right. Not sure why this works, but it does. I left Fusion disabled, but also added a custom password to 'wireless network'. Up until this point I saw no difference between fusion and 'wireless network' - I assumes they were one and the same; however it appears they are not. I then join the wireless network as opposed to fusion and bingo - I am assigned a 192.168.1.x address, and wireless can talk to wired!

Using the default password does not appear to work (it will not let me join - very odd) and disabling fusion means the wireless network disappears (so not 100% unassociated it appears!).

Hope this helps somebody at some point - it certainly had me pulling my hair out for a long time!

Thanks for your help @GregD. You started me thinking differently which led me in the right direction!